# What is the best way to account for duplicate entries in datagridview with C# and SQL?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, visual-studio

This windows application displays student information in a datagridview. When the table is double clicked, another form appears for editing the data.

When duplicates for StudentName exist, when doubleclicking the latest entry, only the earliest entry for StudentName appears. Also, when editing any data for a particular student, all duplicated entries get edited as well!

[image]

I was trying modify the code so that it would load the data based on StudentId instead of StudentName. An alternative idea was to implement a change in the code so that the user cannot enter duplicate entries.

What would be the best approach to solving this?

ViewStudentForm.cs

```
private void StudentDataGridView_CellDoubleClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    if(StudentDataGridView.Rows.Count > 0)
    {
    string studentName = StudentDataGridView.SelectedRows[0].Cells[1].Value.ToString();

    StudentForm studentForm = new StudentForm();
    studentForm.StudentName = studentName;
    studentForm.IsUpdate = true;
    studentForm.ShowDialog();
    LoadDataIntoDataGridView();
    }
}

private void LoadDataIntoDataGridView()
{
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(AppConnection.GetConnectionString()))
    {
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("usp_Students_LoadDataIntoDataGridView", con))
        {
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            if (con.State != ConnectionState.Open)
                con.Open();
                    
            DataTable dtStudents = new DataTable(); 
            SqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader(); 
            dtStudents.Load(sdr);
            StudentDataGridView.DataSource = dtStudents;                   
        }
    }
}
```

StudentForm.cs

```
public string StudentName { get; set; }
public bool IsUpdate { get; set; }

private void SaveButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Do Insert Process
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(AppConnection.GetConnectionString())) 
    {
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("usp_Students_InsertNewStudent", con))
        {
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StudentName", StudentNameTextBox.Text.Trim());
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Age", AgeTextBox.Text.Trim());
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Gender", GenderTextBox.Text.Trim());
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Description", DescriptionTextBox.Text.Trim());
                            
        if (con.State != ConnectionState.Open)
            con.Open();

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            MessageBox.Show("Student is successfully added in the database.", "Success", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
            ResetFormControl();
       }
   }
}
```

Stored Procedure for usp_Students_InsertNewStudent

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_Students_InsertNewStudent]
(
    @StudentName NVARCHAR(200)
    ,@Age NVARCHAR(50)
    ,@Gender NVARCHAR(50)
    ,@Description NVARCHAR(MAX)
    ,@Image IMAGE
    ,@CreatedBy NVARCHAR(50)
)
AS
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO [dbo].[Students]
           ([StudentName]
           ,[Age]
           ,[Gender]
           ,[Description]
           ,[Image]
           ,[CreatedBy]
           ,[CreatedDate])
     VALUES
        (
            @StudentName
            ,@Age
            ,@Gender
            ,@Description
            ,@Image
            ,@CreatedBy
            ,GETDATE()
        )
    END
```

Comment: There are many ways to fix this.  I would do data validation on the database side since, I presume, multiple clients could hit the database at once.  IMHO, `usp_Students_InsertNewStudent` should return whether or not the insert occurred.  And the schema should have constraints preventing duplicates you don't want from ever getting into the table.

Comment: There isn't enough info to answer your question

Comment: What should be added to the stored procedure? I add the stored procedure in the post.

Comment: First things first, I think you want a UNIQUE constraint on the student name column.  This will prevent duplicates.  As for how to change the stored proc, that's up to you.  Data integrity comes first.  You could simply just catch the _specific_ exception when you violate said constraint and tell the user it's a duplicate student name.

Comment: IMO trying to put a unique constraint on `StudentName` is a wrong idea. People have duplicate names, it's a fact or life. You're going to encounter many duplicates of common names like "John Smith." Seems like the double click handler should be extracting the `StudentId` and passing that to the StudentForm detail instead. Likewise, the insert stored procedure should be capturing `scope_identity()` so that it can return the `StudentId` of the newly inserted record via an `output` parameter.

Comment: rel - don't use [addwithvalue](http://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/).

Comment: Everytime I use add I get the message: "Warning CS0618 'SqlParameterCollection.Add(string, object)' is obsolete: 'Add(String parameterName, Object value) has been deprecated.  Use AddWithValue(String parameterName, Object value).  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=14202'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed some code for the doubleclick handler within the ViewStudentForm.cs

In this context I think it better to perform the load operation based on Id instead of student name.

```
private void StudentDataGridView_CellDoubleClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    if(StudentDataGridView.Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        int StudentId = Convert.ToInt32(StudentDataGridView.SelectedRows[0].Cells[0].Value);            
        StudentForm studentForm = new StudentForm();
        studentForm.StudentId = StudentId;
        studentForm.IsUpdate = true;
        studentForm.ShowDialog();
        LoadDataIntoDataGridView();
     }
}
```

Comment: It's not "better". It is **logically correct** to use the primary (or alternate) key value of the entity you want to pass to another "process" for performing some action. Don't start making assumptions and passing just anything. Is there not some sort of Edit button on your form that does exactly the same thing? Perhaps a pop-up menu for rt-click? Are you going to put that same code in multiple places?

Answer (score 0):

A few things:

1. You need to identify something in the real world that constitutes uniqueness for your student. Even a combination of student name, age and gender would not be unique. This is why schools give out a student id that uniquely identifies a student. Once you know what that is, add it to your table and put a unique constraint on it.
2. Once this is set, then you need validation on the front end to prevent an error from occurring in your database if a user sends a duplicate in. This looks to be a desktop app with no tiers between the front end  and back end so should be speedy to check the DB and give user feedback immediately.
3. If for whatever reason, you can't do #2, then in your stored procedure, you can before you insert, check for existence because if you don't check, your constraint will kick out an error and if unhandled will crash your app.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_Students_InsertNewStudent]
(
    @StudentName NVARCHAR(200)
    ,@Age NVARCHAR(50)
    ,@Gender NVARCHAR(50)
    ,@Description NVARCHAR(MAX)
    ,@Image IMAGE
    ,@CreatedBy NVARCHAR(50)
)
AS
BEGIN
   if not exists (select 'x' from dbo.Students where uniquekey=@passedinuniquekey)
   BEGIN
        INSERT INTO [dbo].[Students]
           ([StudentName]
           ,[Age]
           ,[Gender]
           ,[Description]
           ,[Image]
           ,[CreatedBy]
           ,[CreatedDate])
     VALUES
        (
            @StudentName
            ,@Age
            ,@Gender
            ,@Description
            ,@Image
            ,@CreatedBy
            ,GETDATE()
        )
    END
END
```

Lastly, I would do this in the actual code that calls this stored procedure

```
    int rowsAffected = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    if (rowsAffected>0)
    {
            MessageBox.Show("Student is successfully added in the database.", "Success", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
            ResetFormControl();
    }
    else
    // Failed message here
```